# Run Multiple Files From Single .tt File and Add the Generated Files Under the Single .tt File

Tags: t4

I have a scenario in which I need to run all template files under a given directory from one .tt file and add the generated files under this .tt file which was run.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Generating multiple output files from one .tt file is not an easy task. I guess implementing this functionality would be very time consuming.
Here is a blog post about how to use tangible T4 Editor to create multiple output files, even in different solution projects:

[T4: How To Generate Multiple Output Files From A Single T4 Template](http://t4-editor.tangible-engineering.com/blog/how-to-generate-multiple-output-files-from-a-single-t4-template.html)

Comment: [When someone goes on Stack Exchange, the question "answer" should actually contain an answer. Not just a bunch of directions towards the answer.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/171858).  And the link content is bad.